# Convex hulls of hierarchical clustering in Python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, computational-geometry, convex-hull, hierarchical-clustering

I'm using hierarchical clustering to try to visualize a large set of data that has been flattened to two dimensions.  What I want to do is create a visualization that allows me to look at the data from different heights in the hierarchy, by rendering clusters as the convex hulls of their constituent points.  The toughest part of this problem is that I need an algorithm that can efficiently merge the convex hulls of pairs clusters as I move up the hierarchy.  I've seen a lot of algorithms for calculating the convex hulls of points in O(n log n) time, but it seems as though it would be much more efficient in this case to exploit the substructure of the problem, but I'm not exactly sure how.

**Edit:**

For more information, the data structure is an array that begins with the original points of the clustering, and then says which points/clusters are combined to form the next cluster.  So it's kind of like a tree/pointer structure, but contained in one big array.  The important part is that it's efficient to see what the two constituent clusters are of any super cluster, but it's not efficient to get the set of all points belonging to a cluster.  So any reasonable algorithm has to work from the bottom up.

So let's say we're in the middle of the hierarchy someplace, and the precomputed hierarchy says that clusters A and B are merged to produce cluster C.  We're going from the bottom up, so we already have computed the convex hulls of the points in clusters A and B, so we simply need to combine them to produce the convex hull of cluster C.  Cluster A's convex hull could actually be a single point, a pair, or a full polygon.  Same goes for cluster B.  So there are several cases for how these should be merged to form the convex hull of cluster C, but I'd bet there's a clever solution that would probably treat singletons and pairs the same way as polygons.

The most obvious solution would be to calculate the convex hull with the combined set of points from the convex hulls of clusters A and B.  But I need to do this on a hierarchy of 100k points, so I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to combine the convex hulls of A and B.

**Edit 2:**

```
         /----5
    1---/    / \
   / \      / B 8
  2 A 3  C 6   /
   \ /      \ /
    4--------7
```

Okay, so I attempted to ASCII out an illustration of what I mean.  The convex hull of cluster A is 1-2-3-4, the convex hull of B is 5-6-7-8, and the convex hull of C is 1-2-4-7-8-5.  Presumably, clusters A and B contain additional points inside of their hulls, but these clearly cannot possible become part of the hull of C, so the problem is an algorithm that determines where to "splice" the hulls of clusters A and B to form the hull of C, based on the coordinates of the points.  This is the inductive step of the whole process.  (Eventually C will be combined with cluster D and so on, until the algorithm ends with the topmost cluster, which will have as its convex hull the convex hull of all points).

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what exactly you intend to exploit and how exactly the current datastructure is?

Comment: can you add a simple image showing what it should look like? (specially the part where you say "The toughest part of this problem is that I need an algorithm that can efficiently merge the convex hulls of pairs clusters as I move up the hierarchy")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two convex hull merge algorithms that I'm aware of -- [rotating calipers](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.155.5671&rep=rep1&type=pdf) of Toussaint (section 5 of the paper) and the [bridging algorithm](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.110.6690&rep=rep1&type=pdf) of Preparata and Hong (see section 3 of the paper). Both of these algorithms take time linear in *h = h<sub>1</sub> + h<sub>2</sub>*, where *h<sub>1</sub>* and *h<sub>2</sub>* are the number of hull vertices in the first and second convex hulls respectively.

Answer (score 2):

There are various methods that allow you to "update" a convex hull when adding a new point. Also some methods for convex hull and Delaunay triangulation nicely work inside-out already, which should play nicely with this. Have a look at the s-hull algorithm.

However, since you are talking about hierarchical clustering, the convex hull probably is the least of your concerns when it comes to complexity.

Hierarchical clustering does not scale up well to large data sets, because the algorithms are usually `O(n^3)` in nature (making them one of the slowest clustering algorithms you find still used in practice). So additionally computing a number of convex hulls should *not* make that much of a difference, given that your clustering was more expensive. You probably just need a fast, incremental implementation of a `O(n log n)` convex hull algorithm.

Comment: I'll look into s-hull...

My understanding is that hierarchical clustering is much more efficient in some cases--O(n^2) for single linkage, and O(n^2 log n) for some other cases. But if you have other suggestions, fire away; I'm basically looking to be able to render the clusters on a map, choosing the proper level of the hierarchy intelligently.  I've been running the clustering for a solid week so far :)  

K-means doesn't look much better computationally, though. But anything would work, I just need a reasonable visual representation of the data, the fidelity of the clusters isn't crucial.

Comment: It is only `O(n^2)` if you have a *good* implementation. If it is the usual matrix-based implementation, it is `O(n^3)`. In your case, an index is probably much smarter. Even do look into quad trees, too. They're extremely easy, which makes them incredibly fast (in particular when in-memory; the R-trees are better designed for disk operation).

Comment: I've been using Python Fastcluster (http://math.stanford.edu/~muellner/fastcluster.html) which has O(n^2) implementations, although it's still horribly slow.  I'm not sure tree structures alone will be suitable.  I'm looking into density-based algorithms like DBSCAN and OPTICS now, as methods that might fit my needs, and have acceptable performance.

Comment: Note that in my experience, the Weka, R and Python versions of DBSCAN and OPTICS are horribly slow, but it is an implementation thing. The ELKI implementations - supposedly the same algorithm - are 2+ orders of magnitude faster on my data sets.

Comment: I'm really just hosed no matter how I look at it, eh?  But yes, I've seen your suggestion to use ELKI on some other questions, so I've been working on getting that up and running for my data set.  The ELKI documentation on OPTICS is looking pretty sparse, but I'm going to give it a shot.